# How to disable sass --watch initiated folder

Tags: css, macos, npm, sass

Got my SASS working - great - amazing documentation everywhere. `http://sass-lang.com/guide` was the guide I followed.

```
sass --watch myfolder/css
```

Ran a command of sort, worked great - every change to .scss resulted in a fully packaged & minified .css. Great!

However I installed phpStorm IDE, and because it has built-in file watchers for SASS, jsUglify etc., I no longer need the SASS to run its own watches within a specific directory. Not to mention, when a sync happens (when another developer in my firm commits an update and it rolls back to my desktop) it runs automatically and sometimes due to relative SCSS file inputs, a .css file that was perfectly fine on a co-worker's station becomes an error file on my desktop saying it's missing a required .scss file.

It's not only a CPU drain but also causing errors.

Anyway long story short, that separate watcher I set up on Mac OSX through terminal has to be REMOVED/DISABLED and my searches through Google & the documentation did not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it sounds like you have a couple of issues here.

The first is more of a workflow problem, and it's the easiest to solve so I'll go into that first.

> Not to mention, when a sync happens (when another developer in my firm commits an update and it rolls back to my desktop)

Presumably you're using version control....in which case - why are you working on the same branch as another dev? You're setting yourself up for issues doing that. I noticed you used the term "sync" which makes me wonder if you're using "GitHub Desktop". If so, I'd recommend something perhaps a little less opaque. I don't care for the way it hides away push/pull behind "Sync" - perhaps Git Kraken, or the command line? Either way, try to avoid working on the same branch as someone else...

Now to deal with the issue of sas watchers. Sass (as far as I'm aware) does not by default have watch functionality unless you explicitly invoke that when you run the `sass` command with the `watch` flag. If you're not doing that - it sounds like there's something else odd going on behind the scenes that you're not aware of that's watching and re-compiling the sass...

Comment: Not when it's a minor issue such as a CSS change of one of our template files - we don't bother with a full branch, as it's a very quick commit (like.. padding adjustment for example). Yes we use Github Desktop GUI for it so all staff old and new can easily see what's been going on etc.

Comment: Edited my question above - SASS attaches and initiates a watcher, so that if files within a certain folder change, it immediately runs the SASS compiler on all files within that folder.

Comment: Typically, it's a good idea to have one person per own branch(even for small things, then you merge into develop(via PR) when ready. Otherwise, you have the problem where you're stepping on each other's toes constantly (as you're experiencing), and as I said - GitHub Desktop just hides everything behind a big "Sync" button - my last team had issues with it. You might want to try something else like Git Kraken or just the CLI.

Comment: Here's how I understand your sass issue:

1. Your IDE (phpstorm) is watching the sass and recompiling on changes
2. You're using the command `sass --watch myfolder/css` to watch the `myfolder/css` folder

Is that right?